# Loop over getClientOriginalName() on array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

When I am trying upload multiple files in array `bankfile`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="custom-file form-group">
    <input id="logo" type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control" name="bankfile[]" accept="application/pdf" required multiple/>
    <label for="logo" class="custom-file-label">Choose file...</label>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$file = $request->file('bankfile');
$job_id = random_strings(20); 
$filenamePre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

I am getting following error :

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

I want to array of the filename in `filename` or `filenamePre`. Maybe I need to loop over `filenamePre`. But I don't know how to do that as new to Laravel and PHP.

Thank you for time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request->file('bankfile')` is an array, so you need `foreach` loop to get each file :

```
$files = $request->file('bankfile');
if($request->hasFile('bankfile'))
$filenamePre = [];
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $job_id = random_strings(20); 
        $filenamePre[] = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
}
```

Comment: And i want one variable `$filenamelist` which will have list of an array

Comment: @Maqsud, I upated my answer, if you return `$filenamePre` you will get an **array** with all file names